# Connecting two regexp

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to connect two alone working regexp to one, then change them in place using notepad++. 
I have data like:

```
3 blablbalb [308] abababab
```

for blablbalb I'm using that:

```
((?<=^\d ).*?(?= \[))
```

for abababab this:

```
((?<=\] ).*?$)
```

Its possible to connect them? For replace them by

```
\2\3\1
```

where \3 will be [308]

So output will be:

```
3 abababab [308] blablbalb
```

Comment: Your desired output would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use:

```
(?<=^\d )(.*?)(\[.*?])(.*?)$
```

You could switch them afterwards.